# From a list of objects remove all objects where value of a property "colName" matches Any item in a given array "AllCols"

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a linq query but dint have much luck. My skill with is linq is beginner level .

From a list of objects remove all objects where the value of a property called "colName" matches any of the items in an array called "AllCols"

Answer (score 3):

```
listOfObjects.RemoveAll(o => AllCols.Contains(o.colName))
```

Assuming that `listOfObjects` is a List<> (as you've written). If it's an IList<> you can safely cast it, if you're certain it's holding a List<> instance.

Comment: that worked... thank you.... and I figured out the error in my approach.

Comment: You're welcome. You may consider marking this answer as accepted, so that other users will not be mistaken that it's still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can like this

```
listOfobjects = listOfobjects.Where(i => !AllCols.Any(t => t == i)).ToList();
```